# Smokeping web front end on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 12.10, apache2, cgi

I have upgraded a PC from Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 to 13.10.
On 12.04 the URL to Smokeping web front end used to be `http://localhost/smokeping/smokeping.cgi`. After upgrading to 13.10 this does not work any more.

Is it just an issue of finding out the change of URL in Ubuntu 13.10 (with apache 2.4.6) or is something missing?

On 12.04 there is a link from `/etc/apache2/conf.d/smokeping` to `/etc/smokeping/apache2.conf`.

On 13.10 this link no longer exists. Nor does the folder conf.d. I tried to make a link from conf-enabled instead but this did not help.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall `smokeping`, but this did not help.

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 in a VM and installed `smokeping` there. the `apt-get install smokeping` installation gives the following error message:

```
non-standard Apache configuration or missing apache2ctl, not enabling /etc/smokeping/apache2.conf
```

So I guess `smokeping` for Ubuntu has not been completely ported to the 2.4.6 version of Apache  used in Ubuntu 13.10?

Still I assume that it is easy to fix?

Comment: SmokePing [hasn't changed much](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6295651/), so I'd focus on troubleshooting your web server configuration.

Comment: Not a solution, but just to let you know that this is filed as a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/smokeping/+bug/1247982

Answer (score 3):

http://www.gattis.org/Work-and-Tech/service-monitoring-and-security/monitoring/smokeping

```
# Install smokeping and sendmail (the latter is required to be present because of a smokeping bug)
sudo apt-get install smokeping sendmail

# Link in the smokeping apache config (apache2 was installed above as a req for smokeping)
cd /etc/apache2/conf-available
sudo ln -s ../../smokeping/apache2.conf smokeping.conf

# Enable the config and mod_cgi
sudo a2enconf smokeping
sudo a2enmod cgid

service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have this line:

```
Include conf.d/
```

in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` if not add it.

Another option is to create a symlink between smokping config file and site-enable in the apache2 dir, like this:

```
ln -s /etc/smokeping/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/smokeping.conf
```